# Is it correct to use the <menu> element as navigation?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Is it correct to use the [<menu>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu) tag as navigation?
Like that:

```
<menu>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page three</a></li>
</menu>
```

Or is it indicated only for a **Context menu**, like the example on Mozilla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your exmaple you are using the `<menu>` tag correctly and as matter of fact that is the way you should actually code a navigation list.
The `<menu>` tag is a sementic alternative to the unsemantic `<ul>` as is treated by the browser as the same.

To quote MDN WebDocs:

> The `<menu>` and `<ul>` elements both represent an unordered list of items. The key difference is that `<ul>` primarily contains items for display, while `<menu>` was intended for interactive items.

`<a>`nchors are interactive elements and as such the `<menu>` should be correctly used as a list container in that case.

However, your wording is incorrect. `<menu>` is only a container for the unordered list of anchors but not an entire navigation for which the `<nav>` element should be used.

As example a navigation bar could contain more then just links:

```html
<nav>
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Website Logo">
  <h1>table of contents</h1>
  <menu>
    <li><a href="#chapter-1">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter-2">Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter-3">Chapter 3</a></li>
  </menu>
  <input type="text" id="search-bar">
</nav>
```

Comment: The spec [says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-menu-element) it’s for a "a toolbar" where each item "represents a command that the user can perform or activate". I would say that navigational links are not commands. A typical use case for the `menu` element would be a context menu ("Copy", "Paste", …) or a toolbar in an image editor ("Crop", "Draw" etc.).

Comment: A `<menu>` element isn't semantically appropriate for navigation. And it's incorrect to say `<ul>` isn't a semantic element—it is.

Answer (score 3):

No. According to the spec:

> The [`<menu>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-menu-element) represents a toolbar consisting of its contents, in the form of an unordered list of items (represented by li elements), each of which represents a command that the user can perform or activate.

It's semantically appropriate for toolbars. One example of a toolbar is a rich text formatting menu, where users can press a "bold" button to activate bold styling on their text.

Page navigation should be marked up using a [`<nav>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav). If your navigation is a list of links, use a `<ul>` or `<ol>` inside that `<nav>` as appropriate, but not a `<menu>`.